# $U(1)$ factor decoupling at low energy

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, supersymmetry, yang-mills

Consider a (super)-Yang-Mills theory with $U(N)$ gauge group. I read several times that the gauge group can actually be taken to be $SU(N)$ instead because the $U(1)$ factor decouples at low energies, but they never give any details on why is that. Could someone give more details?

Comment: Read several times where? Which page?

Comment: For example in https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.2207 page 5 or in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0408142 page 11. More generally in the context of $\mathcal{N}=1$ of $\mathcal{N}=2$ $SU(N_1)\times SU(N_n)$ SYM.